# POST request with JSON payload with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to hit the Intercom API to retrieve a list of conversations and I can't figure out what's wrong. Here is the code:

```
const request=require('request')

const search_intercom=(admin_id, callback) => {
    const options = {
        url: 'https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer <token>'            
        },
        json: {
            query: JSON.stringify({
                "field": "teammate_ids",
                "operator": "=",
                "value": admin_id
              })
        }
      };
 
 
    request(options, (error, {body} = {}) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('unable to connect to intercom API', undefined)
        } else if (body.length === 0) { 
            callback('something went wrong', undefined)
        } else {
            callback(undefined, {
                conversation_id: body.conversations[0].id,
                client_name: body.conversations[0].source.author.name 
            })
            console.log(body)
        }
    })
}
 
module.exports = search_intercom
```

I was able to wire it up correctly with the web server, so when I debug, options.json.query.admin_id does contain a valid id.

It breaks and says

```
conversation_id: body.conversations[0].id,
                                                  
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here is the content of the body response:

```
{
  type: 'error.list',
  request_id: '<some request_id>',
  errors: [ { code: 'server_error', message: 'Server Error' } ]
}
```

Where should I look? I've tried a few different variations of options for sending the payload and I am guessing this is the issue, but I can't find the winning formula...

Comment: If the body is an array ```body.length === 0``` then ```conversation_id: body[0].conversations[0].id```

Comment: well, yes that's probably the wrong test. The `body` is definitely not an array

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I got the body all wrong.

`options` should look like this instead:

```
const options = {
        url: 'https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer <token>'            
        },
        json: true,
        body: {
            query: {
                "field": "teammate_ids",
                "operator": "=",
                "value": JSON.stringify(admin_id)
              }
        }
      };
```

Comment: Note that you should not use the request module anymore, it has been deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: I'm aware of that. Which is quite funny to be honest because it's still the most downloaded module for doing http requests...